# Grpc & Rest-client context issue

Tags: quarkus

I have headed into an issue with losing the grpc context while using the reactive rest-client for downstream calls. Im unsure if it is my implementation or a bug related to grpc context. It seems to be similar to: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/13959, but according to comment that should be fixed.

Anyway the grpc context seems to be lost when a call is made downstream with the rest-client. I have setup a reproducer repo: https://github.com/AnteLund/grpc-context-lost-reproducer which has some tests to show the issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think we fixed that recently. It should be in Quarkus 2.7.5 or 2.8.0. Did you try these versions? If it does not work, please open an issue with your reproducer on https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues.

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug. It got fixed in Quarkus 2.8 (maybe even 2.7). The context was lost during the REST client call. Now, the context is preserved between the two calls.